# Best way to save screenshots in a game?

Tags: c++, c, macos, file, swift

I'm making a game, and I'm adding a screenshots feature. Currently I save screenshot files to `<Home Directory>/Pictures/MyGame/`. However, I'm not sure if these files will be accessible on Mobile. On Mobile, I want to save them to the gallery. What's the best way to save screenshots in my game? I am not using a game engine, so using any cross-platform helper functions is completely out of the question. I only have access to built-in libraries like Cocoa on MacOS.

Comment: By mobile, do you mean iOS, Android, or both? Are you using any particular engine or library to build your game that might have some cross-platform helpers for this built-in?

Comment: @DMGregory I'm going to be developing for iOS first, but ultimately I mean first. I'm using plain C and C++ mostly, and I do have access to built-in libraries like Cocoa. So about engines that have cross-platform helpers, the answer is no. Should I edit this info into the question?

Comment: Yes please. Use the tags for your target platforms too.

Comment: @DMGregory I don't think I can include all the platforms due to the 5 tag limit

Comment: Have you checked what environment variables exist? There seems to be support to get environment variables in std namespace.

Comment: @Emil You mean `getenv()`? Is there a place I can research environment variables?

Comment: @user147292 I can barely use a mac keyboard and you ask me haha :-) I guess maybe apple has some documentation somewhere? Maybe inside XCode?